# android PresetReverb does not work

Tags: android, audioeffect

```
I am trying to add reverb effect to my mp3player,but the presetRevert does not work at all,here is the codes;
mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.eason);
PresetReverb mPreReverb = new PresetReverb(1, 0);
mPreReverb.setPreset(PresetReverb.PRESET_LARGEHALL);
mMediaPlayer.attachAuxEffect(mPreReverb.getId());
mPreReverb.setEnabled(true);
mMediaPlayer.setAuxEffectSendLevel(1.0f);
mMediaPlayer.start();`
```

I have added the permission `MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS` to Manifest.xml. 
Please help me, thank you!

Comment: You must explain what exactly was happening. Precise your question.

Comment: The PresetReverb does not work.Is there any problem with wy codes?